# How to implement Azure table pagination

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I would like to know how to implement pagination on Azure table storage?

Since Azure table storage does not support "Skip()" LINQ operation, it is impossible to implement pagination functionality straight forward. 
It seems it could only be done via Continuations tokens. But the problem is I could not find the proper example how to do it most elegantly. Can you provide me such simple Azure table pagination example?

In SQL world the core pagination statement would look like:

```
_context.DataTable.Where(r => r.SomeData == data1 && r.SomeData2 ==
(int)data2 && r.SomeData3 == (int)data3).Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

Here we get a returned "page". Azure table example?

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to get the collection of the tokens and page through that, then reference back to the table for the rest of the data, that might or may not work for you though, depending on your match conditions

Comment: I see you preference the use of Continuation tokens, here are some good examples, the second one is well done video, http://blog.smarx.com/posts/paging-over-data-in-windows-azure-tables, http://www.msdev.com/Directory/Description.aspx?eventId=1784

Comment: Here is a refreshed (although possibly still outdated) look at how to do this: http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/paging-with-windows-azure-table-storage.html